# php FETCH_CLASS and autocomplete in Eclipse

Tags: php, autocomplete, pdo, eclipse-pdt, fetchall

I am new to PHP and PDO. I'm working with Eclipse PDT.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from articolo");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Articolo");
```

After that I want to be able to type:

```
$result[0]->
```

and from there pressing ctrl+space Eclipse should popup the autocomplete with all the members and functions of that class Articolo.

But nothing happens, as if the IDE doesn't know the Class of $result.
Am I doing something wrong?
Maybe a cast of $result to (Articolo) is needed?

doing:

```
$var = new Articolo()
$var->
```

the autocomplete popup appear correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$articolo = new Articolo();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from articolo");
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $articolo);
$stmt->execute();           

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $articoli[] = clone $articolo;
}           
return $articoli;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet that you just need to give Eclipse a type hint.  I'm not an Eclipse user, but you typically use phpdoc and do something along the lines of:

```
...
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Articolo");
/** @var $record Articolo */
$record = $result[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query was successful & returned more than 1 row, `$result` contains numerous objects. Each object will be of type `Articolo`.

To access the object's method(s) you will have to do the following:

`$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Articolo");`

```
foreach($result as $object)
{
    // call a method on each object
    $object->someFunction();
}
```

**Explanation of above code:**

1. Fetch the data, so that `$result`  should contain an array of Articolo objects.
2. Loop through each object & call a function name that exists in the Articolo Class.

The reason your IDE (Eclipse) did not recognise the functions in the Articolo Class was because you were trying to call a function from the `$result` variable, which was not of the type Articolo Class.

**Some Stack overflow usage tips:**

1. Always use the search in the top right hand corner. Numerous people have come across problems that may could help you.
2. Always have a look at the [How to Ask Questions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
3. Feedback & always ask further questions if required!

Comment: thanks for the advice, but Eclipse keeps not popping out the automplete on the objects.